# How to add MouseWheel support to a composite control?

Tags: vb6

I have a fairly complicated user control.  It has a scroll bar that encompasses the entire control. How can I add MouseWheel support to the control?  Do I have to subclass the entire control and listen for `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` messages?   Or is there a better way?

Comment: did you install the vb6 mousewheel dll?

Comment: @Sebas I don't need to support for the IDE, but rather for my control that is used in a VB6-built app.

Comment: If a child control does not handle mouse wheel, def wnd proc forwards the message to parent. Do you want to override default textbox scrolling impl (for instance) with container user control scrolling?

Comment: @wqw There are no textboxes - in fact there isn't much there that can receive focus.  What I want is to get the MouseWheel event and apply it as I see fit for the control.

Comment: There is no better way than subclassing but my point is that this might not be enough if you have child controls.

Comment: @wqw What else would I need to do for the child controls?